# Boundary effect in a wavelet multi resolution analysis

Tags: r, signal-processing, wavelet

**What are the methods to minimize the effect of boundaries in a wavelet decomposition?**

I use R and the package [waveslim](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/waveslim/index.html).

I have found for instance the function

```
?brick.wall
```

but

1. I am not too use how to use it.
2. I am not sure the best solution is to remove some coefficient. I have read somewhere that it exists some wavelets that are not the same everywhere and their shape change at the boudaries.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does nobody knows or is the question not interesting? I think the problem arises each time you want to use the wavelet tool for online analysis. Does nobody do online wavelet analysis?

Comment: I lost my question acceptation :) you could have written another question don't you  ? I'm really busy at the moment but find it still very interesting to dig into your question... might contact you later.

Comment: aha sorry for this indeed! But given the enthusiasm of the community for this question, you may end up getting it back again, with a 200 bounty, even without changing your answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a good question and I don't kown much about implementations. Since wavelet is 'mutli-resolution' you have two types of solutions (which are somehow connected):

1. **Modify your signal** for example extend you signal over the actual boundary to have meaningfull coefficients.
   Exemples of that are :

   - periodic wavelet on the interval
   - Zero padding (extend the signal by zero outside ist domain
   - finer prodecure are extensions of zero padding with smoothness condition at the boundary.
2. **Modify the wavelet** (somehow equivalent to threshold or lower wavelet coefficient that are near the boundary). More generally, there are procedures I know there have been many work  since that of A Cohen I Daubechies et P Vial   1993. For example, in (Monasse and Perrier, 1995), wavelet that forms a basis adapted to conditions such as Dirichlet or Neumann are constructed. I guess some are implemented ? If you found implementations, I am interested.

References:

Monasse and Perrier : 1995 CRAS Ondelettes sur lintervalle pour la prise en compte de conditions aux limites

A Cohen  I Daubechies et P Vial  Wavelets on the interval and fast wavelet transforms    Appl Comp Harmonic Analysis  (1993)

Comment: I took some time to look in detail at some of your suggestions. I am working on 2 projects: one to extend the signal in a better way than "periodic" or "reflexion", the other one is the R function ?waveslim::brick.wall, which is a type of wavelet shrinkage applied for boundary issues.

Your post is very clear and informative, it deserves my accceptation, thanks!